# Error al editar un proyecto de visual studio en otro pc

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Visual Studio y este proyecto lo estoy continuando en un pc nuevo, mi problema llega que cuando ejecuto el proyecto para saber como va me sale el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado poniendo un break point para asegurar que esté llegando información en tu parámetro formhija ?

Comment: @LordOfLies cómo creo ese break point?

Comment: justo donde está la flecha amarilla en la izquierda, dale un click simple.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo tu pregunta hice una pequeña réplica

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new Form2();
        openChild(form);
    }

    public void openChild(Form param)
    {
        var form = param as Form;
        panel1.Controls.Add(form);
        form.Show();
    }
```

En la cual le paso un objeto a la función openChild la cual recibe un parámetro de tipo Form y funcionó, tu problema es que al ejecutar la funcion AbrirFormHija posiblemente no esté recibiendo el objeto en tu parámetro formhija por lo cual te sugiero que revises la documentación sobre como usar un breakpoint y te asegures que esta llegando el objeto en tu función

[Aqui puedes revisar la documentación del breakpoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2017)

El breakpoint te ayuda a hacer debug de tu código permitiendote revisar la informacion que se esta manejando durante la ejecución de los eventos de tu aplicación y conocer de manera mas acertada donde esta ocurriendo el error, espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia, a mi parecer pueden pasar dos cosas:
1. No has utilizado bien la etiqueta "if" y cuando evaluas si el numero de controles es mayor que cero, el codigo no hace nada por lo que siempre esta ejecutando el RemoveAt(0) y es alli donde te da el error de indice. Recuerda que la estructura es:

```
if(condicion){
 //tu codigo en base a la condicion
}
```

2. Revisa el formulario hijo(fh) si no carga algun control que necesite tener un parametro, ya que si estas abriendo un formulario que internamente cargue datos o evalue una sentencia, debes mandarle esos mismos datos cuando lo asignas como hijo.